# ASP.NET MVC website loading into an iframe speed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am working on an MVC ASP.NET website, that is loaded by an external website into an iframe.

Is there any specific technique that can be used in the construction of an ASP.NET MVC website to make sure it loads as fast as possible into an iframe?

Thanks!

(NOTE: I have *no* say as to how the external website is built)

Comment: The fact that it's viewed in an iframe should be immaterial to the .NET website.  That shouldn't affect load speed at all.  As for improving load speed in general, there are tons of things that can be done.  Start by profiling it and identifying bottlenecks to eliminate.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers will treat your page the same as far as the downloads go, whether or not it is iframed, so "no" there's not a special technique you can use that is specific to IFrames.  Things you'll want to look out for are SSL mismatch, and integration from the parent page to your page where you might hit XSS trouble. In general just use the standard optimization techniques available to you and everything should be fine.